# Updating table by using multiple joins on the same table

Tags: sql-server

In the picture that is attached, I highlighted two columns.  The left column is a the StartTime and the right column is an ID.  I need the IDs that are NULL to be 164, since all 4 of those rows have the same exact StartTime.  Is there a way to code one update statement to gather the NULL rows and rows with a value, and then update the NULL rows with a value that has the same StartTime?  Any code would be very helpful.

Picture: [Query Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QVsV.png)

Comment: Looks like this question could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293330/how-can-i-do-an-update-statement-with-join-in-sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE t
SET    t.ID = x.ID
FROM   YourTable t
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ID, StartTime
            FROM YourTable
            WHERE ID IS NOT NULL
            ) x 
ON     x.StartTime = t.StartTime
WHERE  t.ID IS NULL
```

This is how I would do it.

Comment: Thank you very much!!!  I was trying to get a list of NULLs and not NULLs, but that was a lot simpler.